# managing un-managed codes in JAVA?

Tags: java, dll, unmanaged

like in C#,

Is it possible to manage un-managed in JAVA?

I want to use system dll like kernel32.dll, user32.dll or gdi32.dll.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Have a look at JNI.

Some useful links to get you started:

- [Wikipedia: Java Native Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface)
- [Java Native Interface: Programmer's Guide and Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/)
- [jGuru: JNI FAQ Home Page](http://www.jguru.com/faq/home.jsp?topic=JNI)

Answer (score 3):

Java can call native code via the [Java Native Interface (JNI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface). [Java Native Access (JNA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) is a wrapper around JNI that makes it more convenient to use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, no problem. Have a look at JNI, the java native interface.